# Is there a way in Teradata convert rows into columns without changing query for new values

Tags: dynamic, teradata, transpose

I am looking to convert rows to column for a requirement like sum of sales per year. A table like this can be transposed as follows:

```
Sales Year
100 2,005
200 2,005
300 2,006
100 2,007
200 2,006
300 2,007

'2005'  '2006'  '2007'
300     500       400
```

The query I used is

```
SELECT * FROM test1 PIVOT (SUM("s") FOR "y" IN ( '2005', '2006', '2007' ) ) AS Temp_pivot
```

However if a new year appears, say 2008 I need to modify the query.

Can I get the output for additional years without modifying the query. Can we do it without procedure or dynamic SQL?

Best Regards
Vaidy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use a sub-query in the `IN` clause, so what about something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM test1 PIVOT (
  SUM("s") FOR "y" IN (
    SELECT year_of_calendar 
    FROM sys_calendar.calendar 
    WHERE year_of_calendar >= 2005
--   '2005', '2006', '2007' 
  ) 
) AS Temp_pivot
```

I haven't tested it out, but give it a try and let me know.

[TD Manual - Pivot](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY~4JcCCcR5Cw/GnnbigJTnAWrDfLbecAN7Q)

Comment: The usage of a subquery instead of a hard-coded list is a nice feature in TD16.20, but the implementation is quite stupid: The maximum number of values returned is limited to 16 and there's no way to order the columns :-(

Comment: This doesn't execute for me - `Object 'test1' does not exist`.  I'm on 16.20.

Comment: hi Andrew, I'm not a Teradata PhD or anything, but I fear you might need to create the test1 table in order to pivot it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs.

Ravioli, I tried the subquery option but it says "select failed. 3669 more than one value was returned by a subquery".

Any other thoughts?

Best Regards
Vaidy

Comment: What version of Teradata are you on?  It may only be available in 16.20 (see comments below).  Also, can you post the exact query you are running?

Comment: The query I used is  as follows. The teradata version is 16.10.03.04.

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  test1 PIVOT (SUM("s") FOR "y" IN (  (SELECT distinct y FROM test1)  ) ) AS Temp_pivot
ORDER BY 1

Comment: Hmm...it looks like that feature is only supported in 16.20.  Sorry, this won't work in that case.